# Java parsing a date like Thursday, May 29, 2008 1:45 PM into a more usable format?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, date

I need to parse dates like `Thursday, May 29, 2008 1:45 PM` for a current project and don't have much time get it done. I realize I can write some custom parser but that would take a while, I've tried a few date parsers I've found but none are working for this, I would greatly appreciate if anyone has any advice. I mainly just need to capture the month, day and year as integers, like:

```
int month = 5;
int date = 29;
int year = 2008
```

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). According to the docs, the pattern of your date string would be `"EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a"`. You can create a `SimpleDateFormat` object using this pattern and use it to parse strings:

```
DateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a");
Date myDate = dateParser.parse("Thursday, May 29, 2008 1:45 PM");
```

As BalusC states in the comments, if your code will be used on machines that do not have English set as the primary language, the above snippet will fail. To avoid this, specify English explicitly when constructing the parser.

```
 DateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

To pull individual values out of the date object, you'll need to construct a [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // or Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
calendar.setTime(myDate);
```

You can then ask it for the values you want.

```
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: Don't forget to explicitly specify the locale so that it also works on platforms with a non-English locale as default locale.

Comment: With the format you have specified, the input date won't get parsed.

Comment: @Piyush: You are correct. I imagine I was confusing the style with Python's. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the help I am trying this after I parse `myDate.getDay()` but its just giving 4 as the value when I would expect 29, sorry for a basic question but how do I get each value to a variable (`moth`, `day`, `year`, etc). I am a bit confused because the method `.getDay()`, for example, is also showing as deprecated in my IDE

Comment: @Rick: You wanted `myDate.getDate()`, not `.getDay()`. To avoid deprecated methods, use a `Calendar` instead. I've explained how in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Date dateFormat(String inputTimestamp) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(inputTimestamp);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.err.println("There was a parse exception :"+ex.getMessage());
    }
    return date;
}
```

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date.

Answer (score -1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)